# Is there a easy way to solve $\lim_{z \to 1} {{z^n -1} \over {z^m-1}}$ without L'Hospital?

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

> Is there a easy way to solve $$\lim_{z \to 1} {{z^n -1} \over {z^m-1}}$$ without L'Hospital?

Here $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Clearly $n/m
$, using L'Hospital.

Comment: Edit your question. Otherwise the solution is going to be $(z^n-1)/(z^m-1)$. You probably mean $z\to1$ and not $x\to1$ right?

Comment: The previous poster is suggesting you replace $x \to 1$ with $z \to 1$.

Comment: Oops! Thank you.

Comment: You could put $z=t+1$ and $t\to 0$ from there binomial theorem suggests $(t+1)^n-1={n \choose 1}t+\cdots$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a difference of $n^\text{th}$ powers. You can write the fraction as:
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{z^n-1}{z^m-1}&=\frac{(z-1)\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}z^{n-j-1}}{(z-1)\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}z^{m-j-1}} \\
&=\frac{1+z+\cdots+z^{n-1}}{1+z+\cdots+z^{m-1}},
\end{align*}$$
using the partial sum of the geometric series: $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k=(x^n-1)/(x-1)$. This is now continuous at $z=1$, and so the limit is:
$$\lim_{z\to1}\frac{z^n-1}{z^m-1}=\frac{1+1+\cdots+1\,(n\text{ times})}{1+1+\cdots+1\,(m\text{ times})}=\frac{n}{m}.$$